# Share connection From RaspberryPi to PC

Tags: networking

I am looking to do the reverse of the usual network sharing set-up.

> I want my Raspberry to give internet connection to my PC, how could that be achieved without using GUI (i.e clicking the check box to share the current network)?

My pi will be connected via usb WiFi Dongle, so the Eth interface will be free.

Sorry if this has already been answered, but almost all questions I found ware for giving access to the Pi from the PC and all involve 'checking the box that says: "Share network connectivity"' which is useless if you are running without GUI

- Model B
- With headless raspbian

### Edit

The PC is running fresh(2-3 days old) installation of Fedora 21 updated to latest packages

Comment: I'm not sure anyone's going to bother with an answer without knowing the operating system you have running on the PC.

Comment: @joan Just did. I thought it would be irrelevant, but I guess I was wrong

Comment: What's irrelevant is the fact that one of these computers is a pi.  You have two GNU/Linux systems and you want to route an internet connection from one to the other with an ethernet cable.  It doesn't matter if they're laptops, robots, blade servers, whatever -- you are best of asking about this on [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), but I haven't migrated it there directly because 1) Hopefully there's a clue here about the fact that you *aren't* "looking to do the reverse of the usual", you're looking to do the usual, so maybe you already have an answer, or...

Comment: 2) If you do want to ask on U&L, you should generalize the question, since the specific make and model of computer A and computer B is irrelevant.  Remember, **if A = B then B = A** ;)

Comment: With respect , I would like to note that there are plenty of questions.s asked how to give internet TO the pi from Windows, Ubuntu and Mac for each of which there is a dedicated site and they get asked again and get closed as dupes not migrated.

Comment: The edit was made as per comment request. I didn't provided the OS of my laptop because it IS irrelevant due to the fact that if the machine giving connection is configured it starts to act as a router for the machine using the connection. And I posted on the Pi site as I think it could be useful to people looking to setup a proxy, DNA cache or whatever without going through the procedure of attaching a monitor to the PI and etc.

Comment: Relevant to the RPi, network throughput is poor compared to most router products. With a wifi-wired connection, using both bridged and NAT configurations, I found the RPi cut my Internet speeds by more than half under the best circumstances.

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov There's a lot of inconsistency to which Q's get closed or not closed because  there are lots of people with that power (it takes 500 rep to vote).   I recognize that and admit to being inconsistent myself.  But the point here is that *the hardware is totally irrelevant* -- as to whether the client machine is irrelevent depends on your methodology, but either way, your're going to get further if you research and ask questions about linux  **NOT** the pi.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of eager but ignorant bloggers who seem to have proliferated a meme whereby the pi's operating system is some special new thing.  **It is not.**  It has been around and evolving for 20 YEARS.  If when you search on line you include "raspberry pi" all the time, you are getting a lot of ill-conceived garbage and missing alot more stuff that might be genuinely useful.  I'm trying to *help you* with this.  I guarantee if you do some research, substituting "linux" for "rpi", you'll get enough of a start on this to ask...

Comment: ...more specific and detailed questions on U&L, which has 10x the community we have here. That would be much better than *further* proliferating the idea that raspberry pi owners need blog tutorials about generic software concepts with raspberry pi stickers on them, despite the fact that they are identical to (and even often derived from) existing documentation for the **operating system**.  That is called **[dumbing down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumbing_down).**   But having said my $0.02 I'll reopen this...